# Software to draw easily sectors with angle on it

Tags: geometry, circles, math-software

I want to draw a sector with the angle on it. I have tried several tools but didn't find any easy way of doing it. 
[image]

Comment: I had to do this for a paper.  I use Maple quite a bit.  I posted a question on mapleprimes.com for how to do this and I instantly got 2 responses.  The first one I tried worked.  I did not have to include any text in my image.  I don't know how to do that, but I'm sure it's possible.  Of course, Maple is not free.  From what I've heard, the task in your question might be easier in Geogebra.  But if you already have and use Maple, you might consider Maple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/nl/), a free program that can be used to created all kinds of geometric images, including this one. First create a circle with center $C$ and point on the circle $P$. Then make an angle of $45^\circ$ from $AP$, to get $Q$ on the circle. Last, there is a function to select the circle-sector, but I don't know by heart which one.

Answer (score 2):

GeoGebra is the gold standard!

[image: Drawn using GeoGebra]